# Django HTSQL TransactionManagementError with sqlite as well as PostgreSQL backend

Tags: database, django, transactions, htsql

I am trying to use HTSQL for one of my Django projects. For that I followed the procedure given [HERE](http://htsql.org/blog/2012/introducing-django-gateway.html) for furnishing HTSQL/Django requirements. Then I cloned the HTSQL repository for trying the example/demo in it from [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/htsql/src/e236a434ad3b/demo/django). The default db used in the demo example is sqlite3.
I have tried this demo on both Django v 1.4 and Django v 1.3.1(had to make some tweaks in settings.py for Django v 1.3.1). As instructed in the [HTSQL Django-gateway Blog](http://htsql.org/blog/2012/introducing-django-gateway.html), I wrote the following code in the django project shell:

```
>>> from htsql_django import produce
>>> query = "/polls_poll{question, total:=sum(polls_choice.votes)}"
>>> for row in produce(query):
>>>    print "%s: %s" % (row.question, row.total)
```

It throws following error:

```
TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management
```

The whole error trace can be viewed at [pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/2197235)

I have also tried this on my own new project but same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use HTSQL from a Django shell, you have to open a transaction explicitly:

```
>>> from django.db import transaction
>>> from htsql_django import produce
>>> with transaction.commit_on_success():
...     query = "/polls_poll{question, total:=sum(polls_choice.votes)}"
...     for row in produce(query):
...        print "%s: %s" % (row.question, row.total)
```

I'm sorry the documentation isn't clear about that. We may change it in a future release.

Comment: Thanks Kirill Simonov, now its working fine:) HTSQL is a very powerful tool indeed.