# Django HTSQL Web Interface for writing queries is not responding

Tags: django, htsql

I am trying to use HTSQL for one of my Django projects. For that I followed the procedure given [HERE](http://htsql.org/blog/2012/introducing-django-gateway.html) for furnishing HTSQL/Django requirements. Then I cloned the HTSQL repository for trying the example/demo in it from [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/htsql/src/e236a434ad3b/demo/django). I am testing this on Django v1.4. The default db used in the demo example is sqlite3. In Django python shell, the queries are working fine now as per [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069384/django-htsql-transactionmanagementerror-with-sqlite-as-well-as-postgresql-backen) question. But as demonstrated on [HTSQL Website](http://edgar.htsql.org/officer), it has a very powerful frontend to communicate with the database and also generates efficient queries ([reference](http://blip.tv/pyohio/htsql-is-a-wsgi-reporting-toolkit-for-relational-databases-5438683)). I am trying to use this particular feature for my Django application which is also demonstrated in the demo/example django app from HTSQL. In the demo app, when I started my local django server and tried to access the following url:

> localhost:8000/htsql/

The page loads and when I write the following lines:

```
/polls_poll
```

to see the data from the *polls_poll* table, the *RUN* button does nothing and so does the *more* drop down menu. No error, no response, no data fetched from the *polls_poll* table. Then I noticed that the page wasn't loading properly i.e [this trace](http://pastebin.ca/2197577) was generated on the Django server terminal. So basically, 
*codemirror* .js and .css files were throwing HTTP 500 error. For that I searched for the links of the codemirror .css and .js files and provided those links in the *index.html* of the HTSQL resided in the static folder. Following is its path:

```
>>> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/htsql/tweak/shell/static
```

Now the terminal trace has changed to [THIS](http://pastebin.ca/2197584)
But still the *RUN* button does nothing and no data is fetched from the table *polls_poll*

Am I doing something wrong or missing something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeMirror just changed the download URL for their packages, which broke HTSQL shell.  You either need to apply the following patch manually:

https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/htsql/changeset/f551f8996610bb68f2f8530fc6c0dbf6b5c34d90

or you can wait for the next bugfix release of HTSQL, which will be out in a day or two.

Comment: I made the "url and md5" changes in locate.py file and now its working!! Thanks for the help Kirill Simonov :)